# 'mighty's meaning in 'the mighty Mississippi River' is necessarily related to the large size?

Tags: word-meaning

I am a non-native English speaker. I thought the word **might** is associated with strength, power, or capability, rather than great size in its essence.

However, the second definition and the example phrases for **mighty** in Oxford Advanced Learner's dictionary are as follows.

- the definition: **large** and impressive

  - *the mighty Mississippi River*
  - *mighty mountain peaks*

The part I don't get in the definition is ***large***. For the case, *the mighty Mississippi River*, is it really necessarily associated with its great size? I think it could be interpreted in whatever way associated with **strength** and the interpretation of it as being large is just one possible way as per the intention of the writer.

Comment: The Lexico definition of [**mighty**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mighty) is: Possessing great and impressive power or strength, especially because of size.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for the kind comment with the link and the definition. But still, the lexico's account says ***especially because of size*** which means great size is not always connoted. So I think the definition in my post, ***large and impressive*** might be needed to changed into something like ***impressive especially because of size or power***. May I ask for your thoughts on this?

Comment: Usually because of size, but not always such as the cartoon character Mighty Mouse similar to the mention below.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mississippi River is in fact large (mostly wide). It has a powerful current. It carries a large volume of water. It is also very long, and has had an important social and economic effect in the central US. (See Twain's *Life on The  Mississippi* among many other works.) Also, the Mississippi River is notorious for breaking through its banks, including when these have been built up in an effort to contain it, and for causing large floods. It is often personified  as impatient of control.

The phrase "the mighty Mississippi" is a very commonly used one, it is perhaps the most frequent epithet for that river. It suggests the power of the river in the sense of its current, and also in the sense that its effects are often large, and not to be easily shaped or changed by people. The alliteration has no doubt also contributed to the frequent usage of this phrase. So in this case te use of "mighty" suggests all of these different attributes of the river, all the ways in which it is large and strong and not easily controlled.

More generally, "mighty" can mean large or powerful or strong. It is often used when the idea is to suggest more than one of these. It is often used where there is at least a hint of a personification of the thing described as "mighty".

The underlying or ori9ginal meaning is of course "strong". All the other meanings grow out of that, as metaphors, or as things which suggest or imply strength, as large size often does.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, especially in it providing a lot of context that helps understand the phrase. I appreciate it. Nevertheless, from your answer, I can not assume the word **mighty** itself **necessarily** connotes large size, but I can only assume it can often do so as per the context. Am I right?

Comment: @Smart Yes that is correct. "Mighty" often indicates large size, particularly when combined with impressive looks. But it can mean only strength or power. Indeed there is a phrase "the mighty midget" meaning a person who is unusually small, but also unusually strong. It can also be used for something like an electric current that is not visible at all, but is strong. "Mighty" can also be used as an adjective to mean simply :"very", for example "I find that mighty interesting".   This use is something of a regionalism in the US, and now somewhat out-of-date. It is often part of a stereotype.

Comment: I really appreciate your comment of answer. I am astounded by how perfectly it explains. Thank you. If this doesn't bother you, may I ask you if I could still use ***the mighty Mississippi River*** only for its powerful current even if the Mississippi River were a small size?

Comment: @Smart Yes one could. But in that case "pwerful" or "strong" would be more likely to be used. Usually "mighty" would suggest impressive in some way, even if not for size.

Comment: Thank you so much for resolving all the questions with regard to this topic. I wish you a happy new year and healthy winter.